# Hide a div added to a layout using set content in smartGWT?

Tags: java, smartgwt

I am using smartGWT, to add a div I used the method setcontent provided by smartGWT and wrote HTML inside.

like this

```
    m_Holder = new HLayout();
    m_Holder.setHeight("10%");
    m_Holder.setWidth100();

    m_Holder.setContents("<div id=\"scrollable\" class=\"scrollablediv\" style=\"width: 98%;"
                    + "height: 80px; visibility: visible; overflow: auto; position: relative;  border: 1px solid gray;\">"
                    + "<div id=\"legenddiv\"style=\"width: 100%; height: 10%;"
                    + " background-color: #FFFFFF;\"></div></div>");
```

now when I try to hide this layout it hides the layout but not the divs.
These divs lose their position and come in front of everything.
What I am doing is this

```
    Label legendLabel = new Label( "<font size=\"3\"><span class=\"nobr\">Legends</span></font>" );
    legendLabel.setHeight(12);
    legendLabel.setWidth(80);
    m_ToggleHandlerLayout.addMember(legendLabel);
    m_ToggleHandlerLayout.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            if(m_Holder.isVisible())
            {
                m_Holder.hide();

            }
            else
            {
                m_Holder.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

This code works fine and hides the div if I use only one div, instead of nested div in HTML code.
What I was also thinking is writing a JavaScript code and call it using native method inside the clickhandler itself and use it to hide the divs outside. But, I don't want to do it that way.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is, make these native functions like this...

```
private final native void hideScrollableDiv() /*-{
    $doc.getElementById('scrollable').style.display = "none"
}-*/;

private final native void showScrollableDiv() /*-{
    $doc.getElementById('scrollable').style.display = "block"
}-*/;
```

and call them in the clickhandler

```
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            if(m_legendHolder.isVisible())
            {
                m_legendHolder.hide();
                hideScrollableDiv();
            }
            else
            {
                showScrollableDiv();
                m_legendHolder.show();
            }
        }
```

Still if someone have other solution, that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try the HTMLFlow component.

But I suggest to avoid trying to embed complicated HTML, I've never found something that can't be done with SmartGWT components only. 
Consider that SmartGWT components will compensate for cross browser glitches.

Comment: I tried that also but it was giving the same problem. and I need this because I am using a JavaScript library for my project.

Comment: Do you need it because you're integrating some third party widget?
Something like this: https://isomorphic.atlassian.net/wiki/display/Main/Using+CKEditor+or+fckEditor+as+a+widget

Comment: No not third party widget. I am trying to directly access one Java Script library. The code that I wrote in answer was my best shot but it is giving big troubles, since I don't have a direct control of those divs.